# Is there a way to resample my data set by random selection from values with the same point ID in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, resampling

I am trying to randomly resample from my data frame. Within my data set, there is a column Point.ID. Because I took multiple samples from the same areas, point IDs are repeated. I would like to expand my data set by selecting one random point from each point ID value so that I have 3 new sets of data.

I am struggling to do this because I am new to R and having trouble figuring out how to tell R to select one from each Point.ID group then return the values as a new data frame.

| Point.Temp | Point.ID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 01 |
| 3 | 02 |
| 4 | 03 |
| 3 | 01 |
| 4 | 02 |
| 4 | 03 |
| 4 | 01 |
| 3 | 02 |
| 4 | 03 |

This is an example of 2 relevant columns of data from my data frame.

The goal is to select a random row from those with same endings for all Point.IDs, 01 to 03, and make a new data frame with these randomly selected data.

I have tried doing this by utilizing the select(), boot(), for loops, etc. but have been unsuccessful.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear to me what your end product is.  If `df` is your dataframe, here is a way to generate a collection of triplet rows randomly selected from the Point.ID
column by Point.ID type:

```
ids <- c('01', '02', '03')
id_rows <- sapply(ids, function(x) which(df$Point.ID == x)) #generates list of df rows by Point.ID type
sapply(id_rows, function(x) sample(x, 1)) #samples 1 row # of each Point.ID type

output_matrix <- t(replicate(10, sapply(id_rows, function(x) sample(x, 1))))
# out_matrix generates replications of the id_rows sampling.
# t transposes output_matrix to a 3 column dimension
```